# Data source in rrdtool

Tags: rrdtool

**I am trying to fetch logs and statistics data from server using rrd tool and shell script, but unable to set the data source.**

this is my step to do :

rrdtool create latency_db.rrd \
--step 60 \
DS:pl:GAUGE:120:0:100 \
DS:rtt:GAUGE:120:0:10000000 \
RRA:MAX:0.5:1:1500 \

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define it like this:

rrdtool create latency_db.rrd \
 --step 60 \
DS:pl:GAUGE:120:0:100 \
DS:rtt:GAUGE:120:0:10000000 \
RRA:MAX:0.5:1:1500

OR

rrdtool create latency_db.rrd --step 60 DS:pl:GAUGE:120:0:100 DS:rtt:GAUGE:120:0:10000000 RRA:MAX:0.5:1:1500